# Windows Server 2019 Core install fonts

Tags: docker, windows-server-2019

Microsoft nuked all the fonts except for Arial in Server 2019 core (see eg. https://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-releases-new-windows-server-2019-insider-and-sdk-preview-builds).

Makes sense and everyone seems to say "it's easy to add back". But *how* exactly do I go about adding them back? Using
`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName ServerCoreFonts-NonCritical-Fonts-TrueType -all` fails because I have no Windows install disk (I guess, error is "The source files could not be found"). Seems a bit dated that I should need to mount a iso file to install some font packs (and a total mess to do in a Compose file).. How to solve this?

As a background, we are running a buildserver that we just updated from Server 2016 to a Server 2019 container and it turns out we have some PDF creation tests that depends on Fonts being installed...

Answer (score 4):

You don't, only Arial in a Core container. Use the full windows base image.

From the source [blog post for build 17677](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/05/29/announcing-windows-server-2019-insider-preview-build-17677/):

> For Server Core containers, only the default font, Arial, is
>   supported; no other fonts are supported, and no others can be
>   installed.